# Xcode 12, iOS 14, Pods

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode12, ios14

After updating the iPhone to ios 14, xcode 11.5 stopped launching projects on the iPhone, I decided to upgrade xcode to version 12 and got a huge number of errors related to Pods for 60 of them ... Basically, everything is related to the fact that quotes cannot be used in Pods, and need to use <> to connect libraries. When I correct it with <>, I get errors that I need to use "", but this is all warning, namely error due to the fact that xCode stopped seeing one library. On the screen all the info.

[image]Thank you in advance for your help)

How to fix it?

Comment: iOS 14 and the associated tools are in beta now and were just released earlier this week; most libraries will not be updated to support them. This should always be your expectation with beta software.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and I fixed by changing the deployment target of all Pods. Most Pods were targeting iOS 8.0, which is no longer supported by Xcode 12.

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure You have Same Version for your deployment target and podfile platform

1. Don't open your Project in XCode 12 after XCode Update
2. Open Your Project Podfile through terminal
3. Just remove all your lib and do pod install (Also remove that extra codein podfile if you have written anything regarding architecture of 86 or 64 which we have write for remove warnings)
4. Clear derive data by path without opening XCode (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)
5. After Removed all lib all other lib again and do pod install
6. Open Your Project and set Build System to New Build System (Default) in Shared Workspace Settings and Use Shared Setting in Build System in Pre-User WorkSpace Settings (You can found this settings while XCode Selected go to file menu and click on WorkSpace Settings)
7. Then Do Clean and build then run it you will not found things regarding module not found you will face some syntax updates or any lib updates fix those and go for run

Answer (score 0):

Try to install pod again, remove all pod and install again.

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

or

```
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
pod install
```

clear DerivedData and run again.